# Reactjs reuse form for add and update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To give you some context, I have attached a screenshot of the current view:

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ3bl.png)

The card, form, search and list are all separate components contained on the edit page.
Currently this works well in the way you can add new items to the database and React reads the (Django) API to display the items as a list.
When you click a list item, the card displays the text by using a callback function to setState on the edit page which re-renders all of the components and passes the card object as a prop type to Card and Form.

On the form component, the Submit button uses state to submit new data. When I click a list item, I would like the form to populate the fields using the passed card object in the prop. This does happen but because I'm setting the state from the prop, you can't edit the form fields as it'll just re-render the prop object every time.

I think I'm getting a bit of tunnel vision here or something because I can't think of an alternative way to do this. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :)

Edit Page:

```
export default class Edit extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        cards: [],
        loaded: false,
        placeholder: "Loading Cards...",
        card_to_load: null
    };
    this.handleCardClicked = this.handleCardClicked.bind(this);
}

async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('/api/cards/');
        const cards = await res.json();
        this.setState({cards: cards, loaded: true});
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

handleCardClicked(id) {
    const card = this.state.cards
        .filter((c) => c.id === id);
    this.setState({
        card_to_load: card[0]
    })
}

render() {
    const {cards, loaded, placeholder, card_to_load} = this.state;
    let card = null;
    if (card_to_load !== null) {
        card = card_to_load;
    }
    if (!loaded)
        return (
            <div>
                <Card_Go_Back name={"Edit"}/>
                <div>{placeholder}</div>
            </div>
        );
    return (
        <div className={styles.page_container}>
            <Card_Go_Back name={"Edit"}/>
            <div className={styles.preview_container}>
                <div className={styles.card_container}>
                    <Card card={card}/>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.form_container}>
                    <Form card={card}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <List cards={cards} handleClick={this.handleCardClicked}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

List Component:

```
export default class List extends React.Component {

static propTypes = {
    cards: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        filteredCards: this.props.cards
    };
    this.handleSearchFilter = this.handleSearchFilter.bind(this);
}

handleSearchFilter(filter) {
    if (filter !== "")
        this.setState({
            filteredCards: this.props.cards
                .filter(card =>
                    (
                        card.race_detail.title.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()) ||
                        card.card_text.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
                    )
                )
        });
    else
        this.setState({filteredCards: this.props.cards});
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className={styles.races}>
            <Search searchText={this.handleSearchFilter}/>
            <div className={styles.races_list}>
                <div className={`${styles.list_row} ${styles.list_header}`}>
                    <List_Row card={null}/>
                </div>

                {this.state.filteredCards.map(card => (
                    <div key={card.id} className={styles.list_row} onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(card.id)}>
                        <List_Row card={card}/>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Form Component:

```
export default class Form extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        races: [],
        loaded: false,
        placeholder: "Loading Races...",
        editing: false,
        card_text: "",
        card_description: "",
        card_race: 0
    };
    this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleReset() {
    this.setState({
        card_text: "",
        card_description: "",
        card_race: 0
    });
}

handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {card_text, card_description, card_race} = this.state;
    const input = {card_text, card_description, card_race};
    const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

    const data = {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify(input),
        headers: new Headers({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
        })
    };
    fetch("/api/cards/", data)
        .then(response => console.log(response));
}

async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('/api/races/');
        const races = await res.json();

        this.setState({
            races: races,
            loaded: true
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

render() {
    let {races, loaded, placeholder, card_text, card_description, card_race} = this.state;

    const card = this.props.card;
    if (card !== null) {
        card_text = card.card_text;
        card_description = card.card_description;
    }

    if (!loaded)
        return (
            <div>
                <Card_Go_Back name={"Edit"}/>
                <div>{placeholder}</div>
            </div>
        );
    return (
        <div>
            <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className={styles.reset}>
                    <label>Enter Card Text</label>
                    <label className={styles.btn_reset} onClick={this.handleReset}>
                        Reset Form
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.card_input}>
                    <textarea value={card_text} placeholder={"Card Text..."}
                              name={"card_text"} maxLength={"100"} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        {card_text}
                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.margin_top}>
                    <label>Enter Card Description</label>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.card_input}>
                    <textarea value={card_description} placeholder={"Card Description..."}
                              name={"card_description"} maxLength={"100"} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        {card_description}
                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.margin_top}>
                    <label>Select Race Card Applies To</label>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.margin_top}>
                    <select className={styles.select} name={"card_race"} value={card_race}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        {races.map(race => (
                            <option key={race.id} value={race.id}>{race.title}</option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input className={styles.btn_submit} type={"submit"} value={"Add New Card"}/>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}